# Mapreduce MultipleOutputs error

Tags: mapreduce

I want to store output of a mapreduce job in two different directories.
Eventhough my code is designed to store the same output in different directories.

My Driver class code below

```
public class WordCountMain {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Configuration conf = new Configuration();

Job myhadoopJob = new Job(conf);

myhadoopJob.setJarByClass(WordCountMain.class);
myhadoopJob.setJobName("WORD COUNT JOB");
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(myhadoopJob, new Path(args[0]));

myhadoopJob.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
myhadoopJob.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);    
myhadoopJob.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
myhadoopJob.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

myhadoopJob.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
myhadoopJob.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

myhadoopJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
myhadoopJob.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(myhadoopJob, "output1", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(myhadoopJob, "output2", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(myhadoopJob, new Path(args[1]));




System.exit(myhadoopJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);



}
```

}

My Mapper Code

```
   public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text,     IntWritable>

{





@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {

String line = value.toString();
String word =null;

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");


while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
 word=  st.nextToken();



context.write(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));




}



}
```

}

My Reducer Code is below

```
public class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>

{

MultipleOutputs mout =null;

protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {


int count=0;
int num =0;



    Iterator<IntWritable> ie =values.iterator();

    while(ie.hasNext())
    {
         num = ie.next().get();//1
         count= count+num;

    }
mout.write("output1", key, new IntWritable(count));

mout.write("output2", key, new IntWritable(count));

@Override
protected void setup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setup(context);

     mout = new MultipleOutputs<Text, IntWritable>(context);
}




}

@Override
protected void setup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    super.setup(context);

     mout = new MultipleOutputs<Text, IntWritable>(context);
}
```

}

I am simply giving the output directories in reduce method itself

But when I run this mapreduce job using the below command, it does nothing. Even Mapreduce is not at all started. just  a blank and stays idle.

```
hadoop jar WordCountMain.jar /user/cloudera/inputfiles/words.txt /user/cloudera/outputfiles/mapreduce/multipleoutputs
```

Could someone explain me what went wrong and how do I correct this with my code

Actually what happens is two output files with different name are stored inside  /user/cloudera/outputfiles/mapreduce/multipleoutputs.

but what I need is storing output files in different directories.

In pig we can use by  two STORE statement by giving different directories

How do I achieve the same in mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

Can you try closing multiple output object in cleanup method for Reducer.

Comment: Ok. I tried that as well. I am getting exception as "output directory is not Set". What does it Mean. I also want to know that the above mapreduce program will work or not

Comment: You have to set output path for the job.You can set lazy output format since you don't want empty files to be created. You can set like below.          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
  LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);

Comment: I updated my code again.Pls see above. Also  I tried what exactly you said, but it produces two different output files in same directories. I want two output directories with different name

Comment: You can specify base path directories using below statements:- mout.write("output1", key, new IntWritable(count),"outputDir1/output1"); mout.write("output2", key, new IntWritable(count),"outputDir2/output2");  Also avoid instantiating Writable object inside reduce method.Define it as class object and reuse the object using setter methods.

Comment: Ok. I changed  it as per your suggestion    mout.write("output1", key, new IntWritable(count),"multipleoutputs1/");mout.write("output2", key, new IntWritable(count),"multipleoutputs2/"); I am getting two directories, but there is one extra empty file created in parent directory.  I am using hadoop 0,20 cdh3 version. From which version lazyoutputformat is available